# mysql most popular articles in most popular categories

Tags: php, mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have 'articles table':

```
id,
category_id
```

categories table:

```
id
```

view counts table:

```
id,
article_id,
ip,
```

What i need is mysql query which will give 5 categories having biggest views count of articles total (most often read category). Additionaly in each category must be a list of articles having biggest view count (most often read 5 articles in category)

So query should return something like:

```
sport, article1
sport, article2
sport, article3
sport, article4
sport, article5
tv, article6
tv, article7
tv, article8
tv, article9
tv, article10
etc...
```

Additionaly it would be great to have how many times article and category was watched but this is not necessary.

I have tried count all with having but with no success.
Regards.

Comment: You must have tried something.  Edit your question with your attempt.

Comment: Also i dont see any relation to PHP, neither code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this in MySQL you have to mimic the row_number() over (partition by category) functionality that would otherwise be available in other databases.

I've tested out the query below using some sample data here:

**Fidde:**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b8d9/1/0

**Query:**

```
select id, category_id
from(
select x.*,
       @row_number:=case when @category_id=x.category_id then @row_number+1 else 1 end as row_number,
       @category_id:=x.category_id as grp
  from (select art.id, art.category_id, count(*) as num_art_views
          from articles art
          join (select art.category_id, count(*)
                 from view_counts cnt
                 join articles art
                   on cnt.article_id = art.id
                group by art.category_id
                order by 2 desc limit 5) topcats
            on art.category_id = topcats.category_id
          join view_counts cnt
            on art.id = cnt.article_id
         group by art.id, art.category_id
         order by art.category_id, num_art_views desc) x
 cross join (select @row_number := 0, @category_id := '') as r
) x where row_number <= 5
```

For some clarification, this will show the top 5 articles within the top 5 categories.

Using LIMIT was sufficient to get the top 5 categories, but to get the top 5 articles WITHIN each category, you have to mimic the PARTITION BY of other databases by using a variable that restarts at each change in category.

It might help to understand if you run the just the inner portion, see fiddle here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b8d9/2/0

The output at that point is:

```
|        ID | CATEGORY_ID | NUM_ART_VIEWS | ROW_NUMBER |    GRP |
|-----------|-------------|---------------|------------|--------|
| article16 |       autos |             2 |          1 |  autos |
| article14 |      planes |             2 |          1 | planes |
| article12 |       sport |             4 |          1 |  sport |
|  article3 |       sport |             3 |          2 |  sport |
|  article4 |       sport |             3 |          3 |  sport |
|  article1 |       sport |             3 |          4 |  sport |
|  article2 |       sport |             3 |          5 |  sport |
|  article5 |       sport |             2 |          6 |  sport |
| article15 |      trains |             2 |          1 | trains |
| article13 |          tv |             6 |          1 |     tv |
|  article9 |          tv |             3 |          2 |     tv |
|  article6 |          tv |             3 |          3 |     tv |
|  article7 |          tv |             3 |          4 |     tv |
|  article8 |          tv |             3 |          5 |     tv |
| article10 |          tv |             2 |          6 |     tv |
```

You can easily exclude anything not <= 5 at that point (which is what the above query does).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems a little complicated but works great.